# how to find the name of child in python firebase

Tags: python, firebase

how to find the name of child in python firebase, there is not a singular source about it

I didn't understand how to do it at all

Comment: While I understand that you couldn't get something to work, it is not clear what that is and where you got stuck. Can you edit your question (there's a link right under it) to include what you tried, and what error you got? That'll probably clarify a lot.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.